# Using Ruby to log into form with mechanize

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to log into a site programmatically using the [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) Ruby library and then access the content available as a signed in user.

```
# intantiating a Mechanize instance
@agent = Mechanize.new

# username and password for site log in
username = "username"
password = "password"

#load site site
page = @agent.get("https://someDomain.com/")

# get the login form
form = @agent.page.forms.first

#fill the form with credentials
form.field_with(:name => "username").value = username
form.field_with(:name => "password").value = password


form.method = "POST"

#submit the login form
page = form.submit
```

Once the form submitted the `Mechanize` object assigned to `page` has a `url` property that looks like this:

```
{url
 #<URI::HTTPS https://someDomain.com/?username=username&password=password#>
}
```

I think the way I'm passing my username and password to the url through the use of Mechanize is wrong because it looks like the website doesn't do that when I go and sign in manually.

**Question**

- Does the local variable `page` contain the response page that is shown once the user is logged in?
- I now want to access certain urls that only signed in user have access to-- what do I need to do?

Comment: It looks like maybe you need to change the method from GET to POST. It's hard to say though without looking at it.

Comment: True... would you happen to know how to specify the request type ?

Comment: I believe it's `form.method = 'POST'`

Comment: Just tried that and updated my post above. Not sure if this is the proper way though